extending holomorphic function
Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $D^*(0,r)=\{z\in \mathbb C: 0<|z|<r\}$ , $r>0$. Suppose that $-\pi/2 < \operatorname{Im} f(z) < \pi/2$ for all $z \in D^*(0,r)$. Prove that the function $g = e^f$ extends holomorphically to $D(0, r)$.
I am trying to prove the problem directly and show that $g$ is bounded and then extends holomorphically but I can't do that. Also I tried to define exponential function from the region $-\pi/2 <\operatorname{Im} f(z) < \pi/2$ to unit disk and take the composition but I can't guarantee that.

For all $z\in\mathbb D_r\setminus\{0\}$, the condition $\operatorname{Im}f(z)\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ implies that $g(z)\in\mathbb H_+$, where $\mathbb H_+=\{z\in\mathbb C:\operatorname{Re}z>0\}$. By the Riemann mapping theorem there exists a biholomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb H_+\to\mathbb D$. Then $h=\varphi\circ g:\mathbb D_r\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb D$ is bounded, so by Riemann's theorem on removable singularities we can extend $h$ to a holomorphic function $\tilde h:\mathbb D_r\to\mathbb D$ ($\lvert \tilde h(0)\rvert<1$ by the maximum modulus principle). Then $\tilde g=\varphi^{-1}\circ\tilde h:\mathbb D_r\to\mathbb H_+$ is the desired holomorphic extension of $g$: it is clearly holomorphic (being a composition of holomorphic functions), and $\tilde g\vert_{\mathbb D_r\setminus\{0\}}=\varphi^{-1}\circ\tilde h\vert_{\mathbb D_r\setminus\{0\}}=\varphi^{-1}\circ h=g$.

what about the exponential function

@abdallahabujahel what about it? $g$ is defined as $g=e^f$ so it's there. $\operatorname{Im}f(z)\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ implies that $g(z)\in\mathbb H_+$ because of the exponential function

@abdallahabujahel if it's unclear why, then it's just the observation that $\cos\theta>0$ if $\theta\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, so$$\operatorname{Re}g(z)=\operatorname{Re}(e^{\operatorname{Re}f(z)}(\cos(\operatorname{Im}f(z))+i\sin(\operatorname{Im}f(z))))=e^{\operatorname{Re}f(z)}\cos(\operatorname{Im}f(z))>0.$$

ok, i got the answer. thank you

The function $f$ has a singularity at $0$. It cannot be an essential singularity because, if it was, then, by the Casorati-Weierstrass, $f(D(0,\varepsilon))$ would be dense, for each $\varepsilon\in(0,r]$, and therefore $\operatorname{Im}f$ would be unbounded.
Can $f$ have a pole at $0$? No. If it had, then, near $0$, we would have$$f(z)=\frac{a_0}{z^n}+\frac{a_1}{z^{n-1}}+\cdots+\frac{a_{n-1}}z+a_n+a_{n+1}z+\cdots$$Let $P(z)=a_0z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}z+a_n$; with this definition$$f(z)=P\left(\frac1z\right)+a_{n+1}z+a_{n+2}z^2+\cdots.$$Then, for each $R>0$, $P\left(\Bbb C\setminus D(0,R)\right)$ contains complex numbers with arbitrarily large imaginary values, and therefore, for each $\varepsilon>0$, the complex numbers of the form $P\left(\frac1z\right)$ can have arbitrarily large imaginary values. On the other hand, $\lim_{z\to0}a_{n+1}z+a_{n+2}z^2+\cdots=0$. Therefore, for each $\varepsilon>0$, $f(D(0,\varepsilon))$ also contains complex numbers with arbitrarily large imaginary values.
So, $0$ is a removable singularity, and therefore $f$ can be extended to a holomorphic function $F\colon D(0,r)\longrightarrow\Bbb C$. Now, take $G=e^F$.

I am sorry, i can't understand why 0 is not a pole of the function f

I have added more details. Is it clear now?

unfortunately i don't

Then please tell me what is it that you don't understand.

This is just an addendum to Lorago's answer -- you don't need to invoke the Riemann mapping theorem, you can just construct the biholomorphism by hand:
If $\varphi(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$, then it is easy to see that $|\varphi(z)|=1$ if $z\in i\mathbb R$. But then as $\varphi$ is continuous and hence takes connected sets to connected sets, since $\varphi(1)=0$ it follows that $\varphi$ maps $\mathbb H_+ = \{z \in \mathbb C: \Re(z)> 0\}$ to $\mathbb D = \{z \in \mathbb C: |z|<1\}$.
The condition that $\Im(f) \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ ensures that $g=e^f$ sends $\mathbb D^* = \{z\in \mathbb C: 0<|z|<1\}$ into $\mathbb H_+$,hence $G:=\varphi\circ g\colon \mathbb D^* \to \mathbb D$ is a bounded holomorphic function, which therefore extends to a holomorphic function $\tilde{G}$ on all of $\mathbb D$. By continuity, we have $\tilde{G}(\mathbb D)\subseteq \overline{\mathbb D}$, but since (non-constant) holomorphic maps are open it follows that
$$
\tilde{G}(\mathbb D) \subseteq \text{int}(\tilde{G}(\mathbb D))\subseteq \text{int}(\overline{\mathbb D})=\mathbb D
$$
But then if $\psi(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ we have $\psi\circ \varphi(z) = \varphi\circ \psi(z) = z$ so that if we set $\tilde{g} =\psi\circ \tilde{G}$ it follows that $\tilde{g}$ is a holomorphic extension of $g$ to $\mathbb D$.

it is great. Thank you

But i think you mean H_+ to the right half plan not the upper plan

Yes, sorry about that! Now fixed.

One thing you should at least mention is why $\tilde G$ takes values in $\mathbb D$, as just continuously extending it only guarantees that its value at $0$ is in $\overline{\mathbb D}$

@Lorago thanks! Added a sentence about this.
